# trying to use UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication in Identity Server 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am making a public Web api in asp.net core using Identity Server 4. I dont want to use any kind of credentials as its a public web api with just client ID. How can I generate access token for users using IDENTITY server 4. I have looked into the [documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html) but there are no examples to create public web api.

Comment: did you ever find out how to do this?

Comment: Yes I figured it out

Comment: Can you post your solution

Answer (score -3):

Set `Client.RequireClientSecret` to `false` for the client, you can request tokens from the token endpoint without any client secret.

Comment: Could you please give an example please

Comment: Setting the client secret to false allows makes this client "public" then you can make requests to the token endpoint with that client without having to use/need a client secret. You get the token from the token endpoint and then you use it as a bearer token as usual.

Comment: How can I generate a token

Comment: The exact same way you usually do? except you omit the client secret params in the request... you specify client_id grant scopes and do the www-urlformencoded request to the token endpoint.

Comment: I am using Javascript Client sample which takes me everytime to login page to login I dont want to login I just want to directly use the api.

Comment: I am still getting the login page.

Comment: Ahh you need to use a client using client credentials flow for this to work. This flow does not require 'authentication' but obviously you wont get any userclaims with this flow because there is no human interaction with this flow. This is not the implicit or auth code or hybrid grant type this is the client_credentials grant type. it's one of the first samples on the samples repository here - https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/dev/Clients/src